# Fetching data from MQTT to Vue app instance

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mqtt

How do can I fetch data from MQTT to Vue app, I've established a properly working connection and I can console log the data but I'm not able to load the data to component's data property.

```
created() {
  client.on("connect", function() {
  console.log("MQTT Connected");
  client.subscribe("#", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
  client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
    console.log("topic:", topic);
    console.log(message.toString());
    this.mqttData = JSON.parse(message.toString());
  }); 
},

data() {
  return {
    mqttData: {}
  }
};
```

Whenever I try to log the mqttData in console it seems to be a empty object. When I printed *this* inside of the *client.on* function I've got the correct Vue instance with all of it's fields and methods. This really bothers me because I can access the Vue object but I cannot modify it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this in the "mounted" lifecycle hook. Here's an example of something I use that's listening to a websocket. It should be similar implementation to your application

```
mounted() {
    let connection = new WebSocket('wss://somesocket.net/ws')
    connection.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("Data received!")
      console.log(event.data)
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
      this.ws_data = data
    }
    connection.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log("Connected! Waiting for data...")
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using [vue-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mqtt) package.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sensor: ''
    }
  },
  mqtt: {
    /** Read incoming messages from topic test*/
    'test' (data) {
      this.sensor = data
      console.log(data)
    }
  },

  created () {

  },
  async mounted () {
    this.$mqtt = await this.$mqtt
    this.$mqtt.publish('test', 'hello from vuemqtt yo !!!!')
    this.$mqtt.subscribe('test')
  }
}
```